# Correctly adding constraints to Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

I have a function of the form
$$
  E(\mathbf{x})=E_1(\mathbf{x})+E_2(\mathbf{x})
               =\sum_i\|\ldots\|^2+\sum_j\|\ldots\|^2
$$ 
and want to solve the optimization problem
$$
  \text{argmin}_{\mathbf{x}} E(\mathbf{x})
$$
using linear least-squares. So, in order to build the linear equation system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ one could choose between two strategies

1. $\frac{\partial E(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_m}=0$ and add one equation to $A$
2. $\frac{\partial E_1(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_m}=0$ and $\frac{\partial E_2(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_m}=0$ and add two equations to $A$

and do this for all partial derivatives $m$.

**My question**: When confronted with a situation like this, is it better/more efficient/simpler/$\lt$your adjective here$\gt$ doing it like in 1.? Or does it make sense to break a function down like in 2.  and add more but simpler constraints when building $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second alternative makes no sense. A smooth function $E(\mathbf x) = E_1(\mathbf x) + E_2(\mathbf x)$ is minimized when $\partial E(\mathbf x)/\partial x_m = 0$ for all $m$, or equivalently when $\partial E_1(\mathbf x)/\partial x_m + \partial E_2(\mathbf x)/\partial x_m = 0$. But of course the fact that $\partial E_1(\mathbf x)/\partial x_m$ and $\partial E_2(\mathbf x)/\partial x_m$ add up to zero does *not* mean that they are *both* zero!

For example, consider $E_1(x) = x^2$ and $E_2(x) = 2x$. The function $E(x) = E_1(x) + E_2(x) = x^2 + 2x$ is minimized at $x = -1$, even though $dE_2(x)/dx = 2$ is zero nowhere.

Comment: Just one remark: both, $E_1(x)$ and $E_2(x)$, are square. Would that mean, that the solution in a least-squares sense would be the same regardless of choosing 1. or 2. For example, $E_1(x)=x^2$ and $E_2(x)=(x+1)^2$, then the minimum of E is $x=-1/2$, the one of $E_1$ is at $x_1=-1$ and the one of $E_2$ is at $x_2=0$. But the least square solution with 2. should still be $x=-0.5$.

Comment: What do you mean by a function being square? Do you mean it is a quadratic function, i.e. that $E_1(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x + \mathbf b^T \mathbf x + c$ for some $\mathbf A$, $\mathbf b$ and $c$?

Comment: Anyway, consider $E_1 = x^2$ and $E_2 = 2(x+1)^2$. The minimum of $E_1 + E_2$ is at $x = -2/3$, while the least-squares solution of $dE_1/dx = 0$ and $dE_2/dx = 0$ is at $x = -4/5$.

Comment: Alright, I guess that is enough to show that it cannot work the way I thought it would. Thanks for your help to clarify this!